# How to persist an object in a java socket

Tags: java, sockets, jpa, persistence, serversocket

I'm having a problem persisting data in the database when I use java socket. I'll show you below ...

This class is called to create the connection, when the connection to the client is
completed the listener is called

```
 public Response connect(int port) throws IOException {
    
    this.port = port;
    
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.port);     
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    
    this.listenClient();        
}
```

Below is a simplified example of how persistence to the database should work when the client sends a message I need to save to the database, the problem is happening in this listener method.

```
private void listenClient() throws IOException {

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( 
   clientSocket.getInputStream() ) );

    String line = in.readLine();
    
    while( this.running() && !serverSocket.isClosed() )
    {
        if (line != null) {
            
            String msgDecript = decryptData(line);
                        
            Entity entity = new Entity()
            entity.setName(msgDecript);
            entityService.persist(entity);

            line = in.readLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to persist an object within the lister does not work, see that I'm trying to run persistence within the listener, I do not know if this may be influencing this problem.

If I try to save this same entity anywhere else in the class the persitence works, only in the listener does persistence not work, only when I try to perform this action within the listener is that I can not save, does anyone have any idea what it might be?

There is no java-side error, persistence is apparently completed, the entity id is generated, and the request is completed, but the database is stuck for a while, I can't open the table in the database, then a timeout error is posted.

If I call the entityManager and try to save the same problem happens

```
this.entityManager.persist(entity);
this.entityManager.flush();
```

Comment: What are you using in.readLine() for after persisting, and what do you think it does?

Comment: @BeUndead So while I'm connected to the client this while it's called, the line = in.readLine(); is used to show the end of the reading of this sending from the client to the server, if I take the line=in.readLine(); I can no longer read the client content, while going reading line after line client messages.

Comment: Just a guess, but it could be that the thread could be blocked from completing by the blocking IO call, which is having an impact on the db. You could test that hypothesis by creating a new thread to do the persistence. It's a quick task to try

Comment: @g00se hello, sorry for the delay in answering, I tried to do what you told me, incidentally, great test hem, but it did not work, because I need to save in the database, and the service that does it in the thread ends up complaining that I need to have an active transition ... i couldn't move forward on this problem